# Live streaming a meeting between two places

Tags: live-streaming

I remember I did this once around 2005, but since then a lot of things have changed and don't remember details. I basically want to stream a meeting between two places. Back then I needed a video camera, a software on my computer and a streaming server.

How is live streaming done these days? Is there an easy way to arrange a live video streaming? I can't afford hiring a professional, so I need to do this myself.

Another question is that at one end of the communication, I mean at one of the places, the Internet connection is not too much reliable. Do you think live streaming would be a bad option for this kind of environment?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need 1:1 there are tons of sites that will do this for free. Start with google, maybe look at tinychat (ignore the scary people), or just search for 'free video chat'.

No need to install SW or setup a special server unless you have specific requirements that go beyond what you have described.

Answer (score 1):

You have to know a little about networking to be able to do live streaming this days.

Fast Internet connection is needed.

check out this link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?gl=NG&hl=en-GB&v=Sm3DfJ2ISRc.

Hope you find it helpful. You can start from there.

Comment: Thank you both Kersy and ethrbunny for your answers.